# Remove known character

Tags: python, python-2.7

new to python so was hoping for some help.
Trying to build a function (so far sadly failing), it's purpose is to remove a specified letter from the word and then return the result.

Example:

> word_func('bird', 'b')

the returned result would then give 'ird' with the b dropped.

The function I'm starting again with is:

> def word_func('word', 'letter'):

Any help would be appreciated. I think I'm overcomplicating this in my head.

Comment: Even if you don't know the python built-in methods you could try with a 'for' loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `replace()`:

```
>>> def word_func(word, letter):
...     return word.replace(letter, '')
... 
>>> word_func('bird', 'b')
'ird'
```

Comment: Rookie mistake clearly. I was using quotes where I shouldn't and python wasn't pointing out errors. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

All strings in Python have a `replace` function.

```
>>> 'bird'.replace('b', '')
'ird'
```

Which functions as you can see, pretty much like removing the letter (or series of letters)

```
>>> 'bird'.replace('bi', '')
'rd'
```

But if you want to only remove the first instance of the letter, or first `n` instances of the letter, you can use a third argument,

```
>>> 'this is a phrase'.replace('s','') # remove all
'thi i a phrae'
>>> 'this is a phrase'.replace('s','',1) # remove first
'thi is a phrase'
>>> 'this is a phrase'.replace('s','',2) # remove first 2
'thi i a phrase'
```

And you can even remove from the end using some trickery, and reversing the string.

```
>>> 'this is a phrase'[::-1].replace('s','',2)[::-1] # remove last 2
'this i a phrae'
```

Comment: You know `str.replace` takes a third argument ;).

Comment: @Haidro I actually did not.. I feel silly now, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
def word_func(word, letter):
    return "".join(map(lambda x: x if x !=letter else "",word))


if __name__ =="__main__":
    word = "bird"
    letter = "r"
    print word_func(word, letter)
```

Prints:

> bid

Or you could use [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and join with a lambda:

```
def word_func(word, letter):
    return filter(lambda x: x !=letter, word)
```

Didn't need to join the output because:

> If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type

Comment: `"bird".strip("i")` returns `bird` - this is not what OP wants.

Comment: if the down voter could leave a comment that would be helpful to improve the post.